# Nothing at input cin C++

Tags: c++, cin

I try to verify if user did not input anything , this way

```
bool null_input = false;
int i = 0;

while (null_input == false) {

char *name = new char[255];
std::cout<<"Name :";
std::cin>>name;

if (name == "") {

null_input = true;
break;

 }

else star[i++].name = name;

}
```

Anyway if i press ENTER without to input anything , cin still waits a valid input. Question is how to correctly to verify is nothing was introduced ?

Comment: Use `std::string` + `std::getline()` instead of `std::cin>>name;` (and `name == ""` will never work properly when `name` is a `char*`).

Comment: `new char`? Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of "char *name = new char[255];", use:  "String name;"  In this way, you don't need to free anything afterwards.  And it's a more C++ way of doing things...

Answer (score 2):

The C++ `==` operator is going to actually compare the pointers. You want to use a string, not a char* (or use strcmp in C style).

For example:

```
char*a = "abc"
char*b = "abc"
a == b
```

returns false.

Comment: This may either be `true` or `false`. Actually I'd expect it to usually be `true` as the compiler can combine overlapping strings.

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
std::cin >> name
```

Will skip every blank character before starting the real reading. The following characters are considered blan (whitespace, tab, CR).

So, it will wait until somthing different from a blak is typed before starting to read in `name'.

Note that this code is unsafe if the typed string is longer thant the buffer size (255).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the non-C++-ness of your code, the exact problem is that `name` is a pointer to chars, and `""` is an array of chars.  The code `name == ""` returns false, since name does not point to the first char in the array.  Instead, you'll want to check if already allocated array is empty, by checking if the NULL terminator is the first character.  `if (name[0] == '\0')`

Now for the C++ ness: don't use `char*`, use `std::string`.  Also, your code to keep prompting if you got invalid data is backwards.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you are not allowed to use c++ `string`, so hope that this c-style code could work for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int name_size = 255;
    char *name = new char[name_size];
    while (true) {
        cout << "Name :";
        cin.getline(name, name_size);
        if (strlen(name) != 0) break;
        cout << "not a valid name...";
    }

    cout << "got the name " << name << " -- it is OK!\n";
    delete [] name;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps, have a fun with `char *` ! ))

Answer (score 0):

You should also remember that anything which is created by "new" must be released. There is a critical memory leak in your algorithm. Heap allocation isnt a good way in this case.

The easiest solution is to use std::string. It is more safe ( there is no memory leak and you can put string longer than 255 signs). There is also I++ in [i++] make sure that "i" will not be higher than a array size ( i guess it is a array). There is a std::vector which can help you.